# How to get sale order list (transaction) in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have two database tables, 'product' and 'transactions' as be low

```
**Product.php**

product_id   product_name
--------------------------
1           |      A
2           |      B
3           |      C

**Transactions.php**

transaction_id       product_id
--------------------------------
1                |       1
2                |       1
3                |       1
4                |       3
5                |       2
6                |       3
```

From transaction table. So the sale order (best sale) is
[A C B]. I tried something like below but not work.

```
$saleTtransaction = SaleTransaction::select('product_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))->groupBy('product_id')->get();
```

Appreciated for all comments, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the raw query you probably want to use:

```
SELECT
    p.product_name,
    COUNT(t.product_id) AS total
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN transactions t
    ON p.product_id = t.product_id
GROUP BY
    p.product_name
ORDER BY
    total DESC;
```

Here is the Laravel code for the above:

```
$saleTtransaction = DB::table("products p")
    ->select("p.product_name",
             DB::raw('COUNT(t.product_id) AS total'))
    ->join("transactions t", "p.product_id", "=", "t.product_id")
    ->groupBy("p.product_name")
    ->orderBy('total', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

This assumes that each product always has a unique name.  If not, then technically we should aggregate both by the product name and id.